# Can a Legendary creature Ready a Legendary Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, readied-action

We got Tommy the Dragon who fights against Mark the adventurer. Tommy spends his Action doing a Dragon Breath, then before Tommy’s turn, has a Legendary action to Claw him. However, Mark is too far away, so Tommy wants to Ready his Legendary action (triggered when Mark steps into Tommy's claw range).

Can Tommy do that, and if so, does it cost his normal reaction to do so, or not?

Comment: Why ready the Legendary Action at all? Why not just use the Legendary Action on Mark when he gets into melee?

Comment: @NicolasBudig strictly Tommy would be at an advantage if he gets to attack Mark before Mark gets to attack him, because he might kill Mark before he gets any attacks off - not so if he has to wait until the end of Mark's turn.

Comment: @Carcer ah, I forgot that Legendary Actions couldn't interrupt another creature's turn.

Answer (score 11):

### No, a legendary action can't be used to Ready itself

The [Ready action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready) is a specific action described like so in the basic rules:

> Sometimes you want to get the jump on a foe or wait for a particular circumstance before you act. To do so, you can take the Ready action on your turn, which lets you act using your reaction before the start of your next turn.

Note, specifically, "you can take the Ready action **on your turn**". You can't take the Ready action on someone else's turn, which is when legendary actions happen.

Additionally, legendary actions don't allow the creature to take any other action than those specified as legendary action options by their statistics. Unless the legendary action option itself says it is Readying an action, whatever it does has to happen immediately.

The legendary creature is allowed to not use a legendary action if it doesn't want to, so it doesn't have to use them up immediately. If it doesn't see any use in taking a legendary action at the end of one creature's turn, it can just do nothing. In the case of your dragon Tommy, it seems like it could just wait to take that claw action until the end of Mark's turn, when Mark will have presumably closed to melee range. It does mean Mark would get to take his attacks before Tommy can retaliate, but legendary actions already break the normal order of things to give the legendary creature an advantage and do more things than it otherwise could - you don't need to make them also able to actually interrupt other creature's turns.